# How to divide my html page to show map and header bar with floating side panel

Tags: html, css, dictionary, arcgis-js-api

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
 <header style="text-align:center;background-color:red;height:60px;position:relative"> map application
  <div style="display:flex">
  Log
  </div>
  <div style="display:flex">
  userbox
  </div>
 </header>

 <div id="mapdiv" style="background-color:green;height:auto;width:100%">

 this is the area i have intended to show complete map 
 </div>

 <div id="righsidepanel" style="background-color:blue;float:right;width:300px;height:auto">
 right side panel , this is the area in which , i have inteneded to show properties when you click on the map
 </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have requested to create a map application to look like exactly as below image ,

[image]

I have tried like this ,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
 <header style="text-align:center;background-color:red;height:60px;position:relative"> map application
  <div style="display:flex">
  Log
  </div>
  <div style="display:flex">
  userbox
  </div>
 </header>

 <div id="mapdiv" style="background-color:green;height:auto;width:100%">

 this is the area i have intended to show complete map 
 </div>

 <div id="righsidepanel" style="background-color:blue;float:right;width:300px;height:auto">
 right side panel , this is the area in which , i have inteneded to show properties when you click on the map
 </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But unfortunately , I cannot make it..

Answer (score 1):

try like this..this way of create web page

**HTML**

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <header>
   <div class="logo">
     logo
   </div>
   <div class="user">
   user
   </div>
 </header>
 <div class="content-part">
 <div class="left">
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d250646.68136366305!2d76.82714579604459!3d11.012014523376545!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3ba859af2f971cb5%3A0x2fc1c81e183ed282!2sCoimbatore%2C%20Tamil%20Nadu!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1574418216890!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
 <a href="#" class="btn">Toggle</a>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar">
 </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
  border:2px solid #000;
  padding:20px 10px;
  width:100%;
}
header:after{
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.logo{
  float:left;
}
.user{
  float:right;
}
.content-part{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid red;
  min-height:500px;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}
.left{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.sidebar{
  float:right;
  width:30%;
  border:2px solid yellow;
  min-height:500px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
.btn{
  border:2px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:25px; 
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: This seems almost okay , but I need left area(Map) after header bar to be fully occupied and right panel will be overlay-ed on Map, thanks